# Why there is no tomcat installer exe for windows?

Tags: tomcat

I was in need to install Tomcat server so decided to install tomcat on windows first but couldn't find and installer exe in tomcat's site instead of many references (on web) how to download and install using installer exe file. installer exe file is available in many places except tomcat's official site. A file - tomcat6.exe comes with tomcat .zip file for windows (that is in /bin dir).

I would like to know why there is no installer exe file available in tomcat's official site in spite of all the references which point to tomcat's official site but there is no such as file. 
Regards ...

Comment: I came here because I also could not find the Tomcat installer, so personally I find this question to be very constructive. The Tomcat downloads page and the Tomcat "documentation" (I use the term in quotes because it makes a huge number of assumptions and leaves out a lot of valuable information) did not help me at all. I've been building Windows servers for 20 years and I've just spent an hour trying to figure out how to install Tomcat as a service. I think Lucas' answer has gotten me what I need, but he wouldn't have answered if this question hadn't been asked.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look here: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

There is  a 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer. Installers can come with different extensions than .exe :)

Comment: Thanks for the response but that is the point I'm trying to mention. Many refer to the tomcat download page as the link of yours does but there is no apache-tomcat-nn-mm.exe in the tocat download page. If windows service installer comes with different extension apart from exe then please let me ask you a favour; could you send me the link of any windows service installer. I downloaded a .zip file of tomcat and there was a file name tomcat6.exe but the file refused to run. Apache community seems obliged us in various way so I, perhaps dared not ask them why there was no installer exe file.

Comment: I somehow couldn't find this on the Tomcat web site until I looked for the fifth time. Quoting from the fairly long list of downloads: "**apache-tomcat-[version].exe**
32-bit/64-bit Windows installer for Tomcat.   Please note that while this distribution includes the vast majority of the base distribution, some of the command-line scripts for launching Tomcat are not included. This distribution is intended for those users planning to launch Tomcat through the Windows shortcuts or services."

Answer (score 1):

Open zip file, read documentation.

Voila!

Comment: Tomcat help says to read RUNNING.txt. That file explains how to set environment variables and then **run** Tomcat, but does not say anything about how to **install** Tomcat. Tomcat help says that "running the installer will always install Tomcat as a Windows service" but just running Tomcat is **not** the same as running the installer. There is **no** documentation in the zip file about how to install Tomcat as a service. -1

Comment: Also, the installer is not available to download as a zip file, so if you're opening a zip file, you've downloaded the wrong thing.